# Emacs M v doesnt work on OS x?

Tags: macos, emacs

Whenever I try to scroll up a pagewith Esc v on os x it only allows me to perform the action once, then I have to release the esc key and press it again. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The ESC key isn't a modifier, like Shift, Command, or Ctrl. It actually sends a key code of its own when you press it.

Comment: Now if your keyboard has a Meta key, you can just hold that down.

Answer (score 0):

Command-V (Carbon Emacs) or Alt(Option)-v (/usr/bin/emacs on the terminal) perform the same scroll-up function and those modifiers work the way you expect them to.

Comment: What is Carbon emacs?

Comment: "Carbon Emacs Package is a Mac-friendly distribution of the GNU Emacs text editor", available here: http://homepage.mac.com/zenitani/emacs-e.html